# $\textbf c(t)$ is a flow line on $\textbf F = -\nabla V$, prove $V(\textbf c(t))$ is a decreasing function of $t$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

Let $\textbf c(t)$ be a flow line of a gradient field $\textbf F = -\nabla V$. Prove that $V(\textbf c(t))$ is a decreasing function of $t$.

We have not learned Line Integrals, so I would assume this should be proven using the definitions of Vector/Gradient Fields.

My attempt:

Suppose $\nabla V=(P_1,P_2,...,P_n)$, where $P_i=P_i(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$ for $(1\leq i \leq n)$, and $\textbf c(t)=(x_1(t),x_2(t),...,x_n(t))$.

These $P_i$ functions will point in the direction of steepest **increase** for $V(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$.

Thus the vectors in $\textbf F = -\nabla V$ point in the direction of steepest **decrease** for $V(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$.

If $\textbf c(t)$ is a flow line on $\textbf F = -\nabla V$, it must follow that $\textbf c'(t)=-\nabla V(\textbf c(t))$.

This is to say $(x'_1(t),x'_2(t),...,x'_n(t))=(-P_1,-P_2,...,-P_n)$,

where $-P_i=-P_i(x_1(t),x_2(t),...,x_n(t))$ for $(1\leq i \leq n)$.

So for any $t$, $x'_i(t)$ will point in a direction of decrease on $V$...meaning that $x_i(t)$ is decreasing for any $t$.

So $\textbf c(t)$ is decreasing on $V$ for each component, making it a decreasing function on $V$.

QED.

Does this proof make sense? If not, how could I approach this proof using only definitions of gradients, vector fields and flow lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. If
$$
f(t)=V\big(c(t)\big),
$$
then
$$
f'(t)=\nabla V\big(c(t)\big)\cdot c'(t)=-\nabla V\big(c(t)\big)\cdot V\big(c(t)\big)=-\frac{1}{2}\nabla \big(V\cdot V\big)
$$